# How to use python variable inside ffmpeg command

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg

I've python variable like this

```
diff #var


print(diff)
output: 0:01:36.992727

print(type(diff))
output: <class 'datetime.timedelta'>
```

I want to use this `dif` var inside ffmpeg command

```
os.system(' ffmpeg -i Thermal.mkv -ss 00:00:01 -t $diff -async 1 -c copy cut.mp4 ')
```

error I'm getting

```
Invalid duration specification for t: diff
```

I also tried

```
os.system(' ffmpeg -i Thermal.mkv -ss 00:00:01 -t "$diff" -async 1 -c copy cut.mp4 ')
```

also

```
os.system(' ffmpeg -i Thermal.mkv -ss 00:00:01 -t "${diff}" -async 1 -c copy cut.mp4 ')
```

when I given directly it works...

```
os.system(' ffmpeg -i Thermal.mkv -ss 00:00:01 -t  0:01:36.992727 -async 1 -c copy cut.mp4 ')
```

Am i missing anything here?...It's not the right way to do it?. If you guys know any reference pls share with me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to use bash-styled variable injection to string, however you need to inject variable to string on python level, and then run `os.system()` on this string.

Use [f-strings literal interpolation](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/) like this:

```py
cmd = f'ffmpeg -i Thermal.mkv -ss 00:00:01 -t {diff} -async 1 -c copy cut.mp4'
```

Another part is preparing your `diff` variable. I assume ffmpeg expects duration in seconds, so you have to convert your `datetime.timedelta` to seconds

```
diff # some var
print(diff) # 0:01:36.992727
print(type(diff)) # <class 'datetime.timedelta'>
diff = int(diff.total_seconds())
cmd = f'ffmpeg -i Thermal.mkv -ss 00:00:01 -t {diff} -async 1 -c copy cut.mp4'
os.system(cmd)
```

Comment: Sorry for accepting late. Forget to accept a valid answer.